Bucket leaking mass in special relativity
While reading David Morin’s book on Special Relativity I encountered an interesting questions, but I can’t understand its solution.
(Set $c=1$ for simplicity). The scenario is the following:

A massless strying with initial length $l$ and constant tension $T$ has one end attached to a wall and the other end attached to a massless bucket containing a mass M of sand. On the way to the wall, the bucket leaks sand at a rate $dm/dx=M/l$, where m denotes the mass at later positions. (The bucket is therefore empty when it reaches the wall). Note that $dm$ and $dx$ are both negative here. (Ignore gravity and friction).

The solution begins as follows:

Consider a small interval during which the bucket moves from $x$ to $x +dx$ (where $dx$ is negative). The bucket’s energy changes by $(−T) dx$ due to the work done by the string (this is positive), and it also changes by a fraction $dx/x$ due to the leaking (this is negative). Therefore $dE=(-T)dx+Edx/x$.

Now it’s clear to me why the string performs work $(-T)dx$. However, I cannot understand why Morin states that the change in energy due to the leaking is $Edx/x$. In particular, I cannot see how the dependency on $x$ arises.
My reasoning goes as follows. The bucket leaks mass at a rate $dm/dx=M/l$. Therefore, in a length $dx$ the bucket leaks $dm=Mdx/l$ mass. How to get from here to $Edx/x$ is unclear to me.

I believe I found the answer to my own question. Posted here, as it may well be useful to others.
For simplicity, set c=1.
The (total) energy of the bucket at any one point $x$ is $E=\gamma m$. When the bucket leaks $dm$ of sand, it loses $dE=\gamma dm$ of energy. Therefore:
$$
\frac{E}{m}=\frac{dE}{dm}
$$
From $\frac{dm}{dx}=\frac{M}{l}$ we know that:
$$
dm=\frac{M}{l}dx
$$
$$
m=\frac{M}{l}x
$$
Combining the first with the latter two equations one obtains:
$$
dE=\frac{dm}{m}E=\frac{\frac{M}{l}dx}{\frac{M}{l}x}E=E\frac{dx}{x}
$$
